# The File API isn't working in IE9

Tags: internet-explorer-9, fileapi

I'm trying to get the file size and file type from an input field from my form using jQuery.  I thought it was working however apparently not in IE 9. Any insight would be greatly appreciated

```
var my_field = this.files[0];

var myInteger = parseInt(my_field.size);

var myType = my_field.type;
```

Comment: And what do you mean by "not working"? Any errors?

Comment: None of what you posted is jQuery

Comment: see what gives you console.log(my_field );

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Im trying to get the file size and file type from an input field...

That requires [the File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/), which [isn't supported by IE9](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fileapi).

---

(And note that `size` is *already* a number [on browsers that support the File API], no need to `parseInt` it.)

Comment: @user875293: Not using just JavaScript and web standards, no. It may be possible with things like Flash, (signed) Java applets, or Silverlight.